# How can I use uv_queue_work multiple times?

Tags: c++, node.js, multithreading, libuv

I am making a C++ addon for Node. And I would like to run uv_queue_work multiple times without having to sleep the main thread. Any idea of how to do this?

So far I've done this:

```
void main(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
//here goes my main code

//Here I schedule the worker, to run BEFOREmethod in a new thread, and AFTERmethod in the main thread
uv_queue_work(uv_default_loop(), req, BEFOREmethod,(uv_after_work_cb) AFTERmethod);

return callback;
}



void BEFOREmethod(uv_work_t* req){

//here goes the code that runs in new thread
usleep(200000);
}




void AFTERmethod(uv_work_t* req, int status){

//here goes the code that runs in main thread

//Then we schedule the uv_queue_work again
uv_queue_work(uv_default_loop(), req, BEFOREmethod,(uv_after_work_cb) AFTERmethod);
}
```

So this works, I can re-schedule the uv_queue_work, but there is a memory leak, if I keep this running, memory usage keeps increasing. But I haven't found another way of doing this. So I would appreciate any help if anybody has an idea.

Comment: I've tried it as well using NAN (this is the [code](https://gist.github.com/oferh/bdde17c52f5bc97fdd42) )
@antirreni91 What version of node did you test?

Comment: opened a node issue [#3560](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3560)

Comment: the [gist](https://gist.github.com/oferh/bdde17c52f5bc97fdd42) code is now updated to run multiple times, the problem is probably that you allocate memory in your code without releasing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! Apparently the worker releases memory by itself after the job is done, so I can keep doing it this way. The memory leak was my code's fault, since I was allocating memory and not releasing it somewhere else (totally hidden I didn't see it), but now it's solved.

Thanks!